Getting UserNotAuthenticatedException after securing the Biometrics prompt with CryptoObject
Currently addressing a security issue related to the potential bypassing of biometric authentication. We failed to integrate the CryptoObject with the biometrics prompt to secure the entire login process. Unfortunately, we are encountering a persistent and random error: Fatal Exception: android.security.keystore.UserNotAuthenticatedException: User not authenticated. This error occurs during new device enrolment, login, or when there is a timeout of the keys (setUserAuthenticationParameters or setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds).
Here is how we secure the authentication process:
Device enrolment

The user enters their credentials.
We initialize an encryption cipher by calling getInitializedCipherForEncryption.
This cipher is then fed into the biometric prompt: biometricPrompt?.authenticate(biometricPromptInfo, CryptoObject(cipher)).
If biometric authentication is successful, we encrypt the credentials by calling cacheDataSource.encryptData(plainText = credentials, cipher = cipher).
We then use the decrypted credentials for backend authentication.

Login (for devices already registered)

The user opens the app.
Since the app is in a "logged" state, we initialize a decryption cipher to decrypt the previously encrypted credentials by calling getInitializedCipherForDecryption.
This cipher is fed into the biometric prompt: biometricPrompt?.authenticate(biometricPromptInfo, CryptoObject(cipher)).
If biometric authentication is successful, we decrypt the credentials by calling cacheDataSource.decryptData(encryptedCredentials, cipher).
We then use the decrypted credentials for backend authentication.

CryptographyCacheDataSource.kt
abstract class CommonCryptographyAbstractCacheDataSource(
    private val keystoreAlias: String,
    private val cipherKey: CommonSharedPreferencesKeys,
    private val sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences,
) : CommonCryptographyCacheDataSourceInterface {

    @Suppress("TooGenericExceptionCaught")
    override suspend fun getInitializedCipherForEncryption(): CommonCipherDto {
        val cipher = getCipher()
        try {
            cipher.cipher.init(ENCRYPT_MODE, getOrCreateCryptographicSecretKey(keystoreAlias))
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            when (e) {
                is KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException, is UserNotAuthenticatedException -> {
                    clearKeyEntry(keystoreAlias)
                    cipher.cipher.init(ENCRYPT_MODE, getOrCreateCryptographicSecretKey(keystoreAlias))
                }
                else -> throw CommonCryptographyCipherInitializationError(e)
            }
        }

        return cipher
    }

    override suspend fun encryptData(plainText: String, cipher: CommonCipherDto): CommonCipherTextDto {
        val ciphertext = cipher.cipher.doFinal(plainText.toByteArray(UTF_8))
        return CommonCipherTextDto(ciphertext, cipher.cipher.iv)
    }

    override suspend fun getInitializedCipherForDecryption(
        initializationVector: ByteArray,
    ): CommonCipherDto {
        val cipher = getCipher()

        try {
            cipher
                .cipher
                .init(
                    DECRYPT_MODE,
                    getOrCreateCryptographicSecretKey(keystoreAlias),
                    GCMParameterSpec(AUTHENTICATION_TAG_LENGTH, initializationVector),
                )
        } catch (_: KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException) {
            clearKeyEntry(keystoreAlias)
            throw CommonCryptographyDecryptionError()
        }

        return cipher
    }

    override suspend fun decryptData(cipherText: ByteArray, cipher: CommonCipherDto): String {
        val plaintext = cipher.cipher.doFinal(cipherText)
        return String(plaintext, UTF_8)
    }

    override suspend fun getCipherText(): CommonCipherTextDto? {
        return try {
            sharedPreferences.getJson(cipherKey.key)
        } catch (jsonDataException: JsonDataException) {
            Timber.e(jsonDataException.message, jsonDataException)
            null
        }
    }

    override suspend fun setCipherText(ciphertextWrapper: CommonCipherTextDto?) {
        sharedPreferences.setJson(cipherKey.key, ciphertextWrapper)
    }

    open fun getOrCreateCryptographicSecretKey(keyName: String): SecretKey {
        val paramsBuilder = KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(keyName, PURPOSE_ENCRYPT or PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
        paramsBuilder.apply {
            setBlockModes(ENCRYPTION_BLOCK_MODE)
            setEncryptionPaddings(ENCRYPTION_PADDING)
            setKeySize(KEY_SIZE)
            if (SDK_INT >= Q) {
                setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
                setInvalidatedByBiometricEnrollment(true)
            }
            if (CommonEnvironment.isRunningTest) {
                return@apply
            }
            if (SDK_INT >= R) {
                val authType = AUTH_DEVICE_CREDENTIAL or AUTH_BIOMETRIC_STRONG
                setUserAuthenticationParameters(ACCOUNT_ACCESS_CERTIFICATE_AUTHENTICATION_VALIDITY_SECONDS, authType)
            } else {
                @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
                setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds(ACCOUNT_ACCESS_CERTIFICATE_AUTHENTICATION_VALIDITY_SECONDS)
            }
        }

        val keyGenParams = paramsBuilder.build()
        val keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(
            ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM,
            CRYPTOGRAPHIC_KEYSTORE_TYPE,
        )
        keyGenerator.init(keyGenParams)
        return keyGenerator.generateKey()
    }

    private fun getCipher(): CommonCipherDto {
        val transformation = "$ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM/$ENCRYPTION_BLOCK_MODE/$ENCRYPTION_PADDING"
        return CommonCipherDto(Cipher.getInstance(transformation))
    }

    private fun clearKeyEntry(keyName: String) {
        val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(CRYPTOGRAPHIC_KEYSTORE_TYPE)
        keyStore.load(null)
        keyStore.deleteEntry(keyName)
    }

    companion object {
        const val CRYPTOGRAPHIC_KEYSTORE_TYPE = "AndroidKeyStore"

        private const val KEY_SIZE = 256
        private const val ENCRYPTION_BLOCK_MODE = BLOCK_MODE_GCM
        private const val ENCRYPTION_PADDING = ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE
        private const val ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM = KEY_ALGORITHM_AES

        private const val AUTHENTICATION_TAG_LENGTH = 128
    }
}


CommonBiometricPromptHelper.kt
class CommonBiometricPromptHelper(
    override val fragment: Fragment,
    override val titleRes: Int,
    override val cancelRes: Int? = null,
    override val allowedAuthenticators: Int,
    override val callback: CommonBiometricAuthenticationCallback,
) : CommonBiometricBasePromptHelper(fragment, titleRes, cancelRes, allowedAuthenticators, callback), DefaultLifecycleObserver {

    private var biometricPrompt: BiometricPrompt? = null

    init {
        fragment.viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle.addObserver(this)
        biometricPrompt = buildBiometricPrompt()
    }

    ...

    override fun authenticate(cipher: Cipher?) {
        // On versions starting from Android 11 (API 30), cipher is required for authentication.
        if (SDK_INT > Q && cipher == null) {
            throw CommonBiometricAuthenticationError()
        }
        biometricPrompt = buildBiometricPrompt()
        val biometricPromptInfo = buildBiometricPromptInfo()
        fragment.view?.safePost {
            if (SDK_INT <= Q) {
                biometricPrompt?.authenticate(biometricPromptInfo)
            } else if (cipher != null) {
                biometricPrompt?.authenticate(biometricPromptInfo, CryptoObject(cipher))
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}

